# Use cases for threading and asyncio in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I've read quite a few articles on threading and asyncio modules in python and the major difference I can seem to draw (correct me if I'm wrong) is that in,

**threading**: multiple threads can be used to execute the python program and these threads are juggled by the OS itself. Further only when non blocking I/O is happening on a thread the GIL lock can be released to allow another thread to use it (since GIL makes python interpreter single threaded). This is also more resource intensive than asyncio io, since multiple threads will be utilising multiple resources.

**asyncio**: one single thread can have multiple tasks/coroutines that multitask cooperatively to achieve concurrency. Here, the issue of GIL doesn't arise since it is on a single thread anyway and whenever one non blocking I/O bound task is happening, python interpreter can be used by another coroutine - and all of this is managed by asyncio's event loop.

Also, one article: http://masnun.rocks/2016/10/06/async-python-the-different-forms-of-concurrency/
says,

```
if io_bound:
    if io_very_slow:
        print("Use Asyncio")
    else:
       print("Use Threads")
else:
    print("Multi Processing")
```

I'd like to understand, just for better clarity, why exactly we can't use asyncio and threading as substitutes for each other, given we have sufficient resources available. Use cases of when to use what would help understand better. Further, since this topic is very new for me, there might be gaps in my understanding, so any kind of resources, explanations and corrections would be really appreciated.

Comment: Multithreading sucks in python. I always use asyncio (which also sucks in python)

Comment: I would add to what you've already said: threading is pre-emptive (thread switching is not under the programmer's control), but asyncio is co-operative (task switching only occurs on await statements).  Threading is therefore far more prone to subtle bugs, and that's a good enough reason to use asyncio if possible.  Pure Python is not a great choice for number crunching anyway, so choosing Python as a language and then complaining about performance has never made much sense to me.