# Threading is replaceable in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, gil

I have done some reading on the topic and [found that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435284/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-vs-asyncio) we can use `threading` if some problem is **io-bounded** but **io is not very slow**. But I couldn't understand why we still couldn't use `asyncio`? Since python `threading` is anyway runs on a single thread because of the GIL, what make it more useful than `asyncio`?

I.e, in Python is there any problem where `threading` is more useful than using `asyncio` or `multiprocessing`?

I found tons of example of each and differences between each, but still could not find a single source explaining a clear use case of Python threading.

Thank you.

Note: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471729/use-cases-for-threading-and-asyncio-in-python) sounds similar, but I understand why multiprocessing is important when a python process is CPU heavy and can independently run without minimal communication.

Comment: Check if either of these answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules

Comment: @JonSG thank you, but both of them argue the advantage of Multiprocessing (MP) over threading, which I understand (because of Python GIL, threading only runs in one thread, but MP is not limited to that). But I am concerned where to use Threading when we have asyncio and MP. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Python multithreading is not for performance, it's for making coding easier.

Comment: threading is older. It will also work in more cases as if forces a context switch. For asyncio to run in a single thread every library must surrender control to the event loop from time to time. Threading forces a switch, asyncio depends on co-routines surrendering control to the event loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911403/6242321

Comment: `threading` is easier since it uses regular code but has lower control. `asyncio` has more control but requires async definitions and a main loop. . . so now you (the user) can choose.

Comment: Threading will work for older or legacy code that isn't written with asyncio in mind. Think db drivers, code that calls into C, things like that. Then, there are APIs that don't lend themselves to async due to OS limitatoins, such as reading from plain files. Finally, there are extensions out there that actually releases the GIL (when safe to do so), in which case threading will actually use multiple cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking whether it is "replaceable", I'm interpreting the focus of your question as being whether threading can do anything that asyncio cannot.

The reality that Python has a GIL *does* seriously diminish what would have been threading's greatest strength: its ability to facilitate *concurrent* processing (of course, Python is starting to finally address this limitation).

Asyncio on its own does not inherently allow for any concurrent processing at all. All it tries to do is provide a clean model for making optimal use of the underlying OS's support for asynchronous IO and of the possibility of doing 'other work' during time that would normally be wasted on blocking IO calls.

Assuming you *do* have access to an asynchronous version of whatever IO you want to do, then I agree that threading is completely superfluous.

**edit, adding more explanation about async libraries**

But, if you don't have a suitable async library then threading is still a good option. For operations such as making a web request, maybe you were using `http` package.  You might just switch to the `httpx` package to get access to *awaitable* versions of `get()`, `post()` etc.  However, if you are relying on a library which interfaces with an API, for example maybe you are using a package that interfaces with *twitter*, that package may not have functions in it that return an *awaitable*.  When you call `get_tweet(id)` or whatever, it may just not return until it has your response.  In that case, that is a blocking library and you will not get benefit from async there. So, if you can't find another package for talking to Twitter, then you might be better off using threading (though you still have to ensure that the package you are using is threadsafe... so you're probably still out of luck).

And with upcoming changes to the GIL in Python, threading will probably see a significant increase in usefulness (as people start using it for concurrent processing).

**Edit: removing the part showing a threading performance comparison**

Comment: `asyncio` gives the user control and can avoid race conditions. `threading` does not avoid race conditions.

Comment: thanks. just to clarify, I added the 'io is not very slow' from another stack overflow answer (linked above) that suggests to use threading in that scenario. it was not the point of the question. sorry for the confusion. But the first half explains what I needed.

Comment: Can you please explain me what you meant by `Assuming you do have access to an asynchronous version of whatever IO you want to do` ? Thank you.

Comment: @wenuka - I've added a bit more detail using an example about a fictional Twitter package and the more real 'http' vs' httpx' packages.